# How can I block access to USB drives?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, usb, big-sur

In an office environment I need to block access to USB drives for security reasons. I know how to do this on Windows, but how can I accomplish this on macOS?

Comment: Potentially related: https://superuser.com/questions/531673/disable-auto-mounting-of-all-unknown-drives-on-os-x

Comment: Have you tried Google? first two links: https://www.hawkdive.com/block-or-disable-usb-storage-devices-on/ and https://www.manageengine.com/products/desktop-central/block-usb-mac-script.html